# Reading of 退く meaning "Go away"

Tags: nuances, kanji, readings

Here is a passage from my Japanese Bible

> 更に、悪魔はイエスを非常に高い山に連れて行き、世のすべての国々とその繁栄ぶりを見せて、「もし、ひれ伏してわたしを拝むなら、これをみんな与えよう」と言った。すると、イエスは言われた。「**退け**、サタン。『あなたの神である主を拝み、ただ主に仕えよ』と書いてある。」　－　マタイによる[福音書]{ふく・いん・しょ}４章：８－１０節
>
> Then the Devil took Jesus to a very high mountain and showed him all the kingdoms of the world in all their greatness.  "All this I will give you, " the Devil said, "if you kneel down and worship me."  Then Jesus answered, "**Go away**, Satan!  The scripture says, 'Worship the Lord your God and serve only him!' " - Matthew 4:8-10

So the choices we have are `しりぞけ`, `どけ`, `ひけ`, and `のけ`.  I know all of these readings overlap at least somewhat in meaning, so I'm not really sure which one is best.  I think `どけ` would be more for "get out of my way" rather than "go away", but that would imply some kind of movement on Jesus' part (the pre- and proceeding verses don't indicate he was walking or otherwise mobile).  `しりぞけ` just sounds too long and unnatural, although that's just a subjective assessment.  `ひけ` feels the most natural to me.

So which one is it?  Or is more than one acceptable in this context?

Comment: 私なら「しりぞけ、サタン」って読むと思います

Comment: FWIW the Meiji bible says "サタンよ退け" with furigana indicating the reading しりぞけ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without looking at anything, I would have to say that 「しりぞけ」 would be the most natural choice.  If it were どけ, ひけ or のけ, a good writer or translator would have written it in hiragana.